# How to install pecl memcached extension on wamp?

Tags: wamp, pecl

I need to install memcached for my windows 64bit wamp running on localhost. My specific php version is 5.5.12.

I am using version 2.2.0 of the extension found here:
http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

How do I install the extension as it is a .tgz file?

I tried finding a working dll for this extension without any success.

Comment: I reworded the title to fit what you are asking. I also cleaned up the body of the message to be clear and concise. This question *might* not be in scope on SO as its related to how to install an application/module on windows and less to do about a code issue. I would not repost this but these types of questions might better be asked on SuperUser SE.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Check in your PHP’s extension directory (like: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext) if not exists file php_memcache.dll, go to the page http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/
to download this file (depends on your PHP version) and put php_memcache.dll in your directory C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext

Step 2:
Edit your file php.ini, add this line:
extension=php_memcache.dll

Step 3: restart apache
and check now your phpinfo[image]

Comment: He is asking about memcached not memcache. Worst naming ever.